# mostrar/ocultar formulário usando botões e javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Eu preciso mostrar um formulário usando um botão e escondê-lo quando o usuário pressiona outro botão, porque o outro botão deverá mostrar uma tabela alimentada com dados do banco. Eu usei a resposta a seguir como base e consegui ocultar e mostrar o formulário porém ao tentar fazer algo similar com a tabela o site buga e ambos ficam sobrepostos.

OBS: eu estou utilizando bootstrap 4 e jquery-3.4.1

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104772/154025

```
<?php
include ('menu.php');
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/painel.css">

<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Clientes</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="container">

     <!--
      ########################################################################################################################################################### BUTTONS ###################################################################################################################################################################-->

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Mudarestado('formulario')">Novo</button>
      <button type="button"class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="#">Listar</button> 

      <!--
      ########################################################################################################################################################### FORMULARIO ################################################################################################################################################################-->

      <form id="formulario" method="POST" action="cadastrar.php">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="inputNome">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="inputSobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sobrenome" placeholder="Ultimo Nome">
                </div>
            </div>
          <div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio1">Masculino</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Feminino">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio2">Feminino</label>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label >CPF</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CPF" id="CPF" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
                </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-">
                <label for="inputAddress">Endereço</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Endereço" placeholder="RAU-SC">
            </div>
            </div>
                <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">Savar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
      </form>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">Sobrenome</th>
            <th scope="col">CPF</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <!--
            dados manuais...
            não esquecer de fazer as inserção dos dados do banco
            -->
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>

 </main>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/painel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#CPF").mask("000.000.000-00")
    })
  </script>
```

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  document.getElementById(el).classList.toggle('mostrar');
}
```

```css
#formulario {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s;
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 78em;
    position: absolute;
}

#formulario.mostrar {
    opacity: 1;
}

#tabela {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s;
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 78em;
    position: absolute;
}

#tabela.mostrar {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, vc esta usando bootstrap? Qual versão? Cade o seu script completo de ocultar e esconder os elementos? E se vc criou algum css extra além do original do bootstrap coloque tbm o CSS que vc fez, sem isso não da pra te responder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara seu código tinha alguns problemas, o principal é que vc não colocou o `id="tabela"` na sua `<table>`, então ela não pegava o CSS e o função do clique não estava funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segundo "problema" é que tanto a tabela quanto o formulário não têm cor de `background`, então quando um aparece por cima do outro vc fica vendo essa sobreposição dos elementos. A forma mas prática para resolver isso é colocando uma cor de `background` nesse elementos igual a cor de fundo da página, `#fff`.

Outra dica, diminua tb o tempo do `transition`, `1.5s` é muito demorado, tão demorado que os elementos se misturam um no outro durante a transição, eu recomendo que use `400ms` no máximo, mas no seu código eu mudei apenas para `1.0s` para melhorar um pouco esse ponto, mas depois vc coloca como achar melhor...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    #formulario {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 1.0s;
      border: 1px solid #ccf;
      padding: 1em;
      width: 78em;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff !important;
  }
  
  #formulario.mostrar {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  
  #tabela {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 1.0s;
      border: 1px solid #ccf;
      padding: 1em;
      width: 78em;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff !important;
  }
  
  #tabela.mostrar {
      opacity: 1;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
      <h1 class="h2">Clientes</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
  
       <!--
        ########################################################################################################################################################### BUTTONS ###################################################################################################################################################################-->
  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-mostrar" onclick="Mudarestado('formulario')">Novo</button>
        <button type="button"class="btn btn-secondary btn-mostrar" onclick="Mudarestado('tabela')">Listar</button> 
  
        <!--
        ########################################################################################################################################################### FORMULARIO ################################################################################################################################################################-->
  
        <form id="formulario" method="POST" action="cadastrar.php">
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col">
                      <label for="inputNome">Nome</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <label for="inputSobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sobrenome" placeholder="Ultimo Nome">
                  </div>
              </div>
            <div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio1">Masculino</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Feminino">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio2">Feminino</label>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                      <label >CPF</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CPF" id="CPF" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-">
                  <label for="inputAddress">Endereço</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Endereço" placeholder="RAU-SC">
              </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">Savar</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Cancelar</button>
                  </div>
        </form>

        <table class="table" id="tabela">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Nome</th>
              <th scope="col">Sobrenome</th>
              <th scope="col">CPF</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!--
              dados manuais...
              não esquecer de fazer as inserção dos dados do banco
              -->
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  
   </main>
  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/painel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //$(document).ready(function(){
        //$("#CPF").mask("000.000.000-00")
      //})
      function Mudarestado(el) {
        document.getElementById(el).classList.toggle('mostrar');
      }
    </script>

  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok amigo funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Comment: @EmersonFreitas legal que deu certo, tmj 